# How to trigger an event (together) in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

i have created an EventListener for each button but i have button generation all and i need to call all events at once.I tried to put everything inside a function, but I don't know how to activate all events.
I would be very grateful for any help

[image]

Comment: like `element1.click();element2.click();element3.click();` ?

Comment: When possible, please post your code, instead of an image

Comment: According to Stack Overflow guidelines, **do not** share images of code. Instead, copy and paste the code from your editor into a code block. The Markdown formatting will syntax-colour it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just call HTMLElement.click() on everyelement to simulate the click on every element. You can read more about it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/click

```
buttonAll.addEventListener('click', ()=> {
    nameButton.click();
    balanceButton.click();
    ageButton.click();
    documentButton.click();
    levelButton.click();
    buttonClear.click();
})
```

if the list can grow then you might want to group the elements in an array to keep the function short

```
let buttonAllTargets = [
    nameButton,
    balanceButton,
    ageButton,
    documentButton,
    levelButton,
    buttonClear
];

buttonAllTargets.forEach(element => element.click());
buttonAll.addEventListener('click', ()=> {
    buttonAllTargets.forEach(element => element.click());
})
```